# Exclude all information from filter in API, then add whitelist of properties

Tags: support, api

Here's a [list of possible fields](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question) retrieved by stackexchange `/questions` API. The green checkmarks mark items that are retrieved by default, red crosses mark items that must be explicitly asked for.

I would like to disable everything except the items I'm interested in (`body`, `title`). Is there other way than explicitly setting all other default items to false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using a filter. You first have to create on, then you can run a request specifying that filter.

From the [documentation](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters):

> An application excludes fields by creating a filter (via /filter/create) and passing it to a method in the filter parameter.

So go to the [filter creation page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/create-filter), select the fields you want in the right-upper drop-down, and use that filter to get some data!

> [image]

Comment: Is that filter something that will be stored on stackexchange servers and referenced by a name later on?

Comment: Yes, it does. You can call `filters/create` from your program too of course.

Comment: I still don't understand. I have no idea where should I select the fields and what kind of fields are we talking about. I tried to *"inherit "* the `none` empty filter and add `body_markdown` and `title` to it as the fields I want. This is the filled form screenshot: [image description](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IG59a.png) I think API's complexity is way ahead of documentation.

Comment: See the **default filter** at the right-upper corner? Your field selection is there.